# alter font size in bootstrap glyphicon break alignment in a display table layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to create a style where some squares are aligned with an arrow made with bootstrap glyphicon. To made this i've created some custom style used display as table css code.

When i use normal style for glyphicon everything is ok, but when i try to alter the font size of the glyphicon, since i want it larger, the glyphicon goes not in line with the rest of the design and goes higher. I've tried to change position from top, text position and so on, but nothing worked. Someone can solve this problem?

Here's the code: (glyphicon is not really shown since i haven't included the proper resource, but the design is altered anyway)

```css
.recipe {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}
.recipe_small {
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
}
.recipe_large {
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
}
.common_recipe {
 border-color: #5e5e5e;
}
.uncommon_recipe{
 border-color: green;
}
.rare_recipe {
 border-color: blue;
}
.epic_recipe {
 border-color: purple;
}
.common_bg{
 background-color: #5e5e5e;
}
.uncommon_bg {
 background-color: green;
}
.rare_bg {
 background-color: blue;
}
.epic_bg {
 background-color: purple;
}
.tablelike{
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}
.table-row{
  display: table-row;
}
.table-cell, .table-head{
  display: table-cell;
}
.table-head{
  font-weight:bold;
}
.glyphicon-large {
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.fantamondi.it/cotli/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Normal size, everything is in line
<div class="tablelike">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="tablelike">
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell"><div class="recipe recipe_small common_recipe common_bg">&nbsp;</div></div>
          <div class="table-cell"><div class="recipe recipe_small uncommon_recipe uncommon_bg">&nbsp;</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell"><div class="recipe recipe_small rare_recipe">&nbsp;</div></div>
          <div class="table-cell"><div class="recipe recipe_small epic_recipe epic_bg">&nbsp;</div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="recipe recipe_large rare_recipe rare_bg">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="recipe"><span title="Can be crafted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up epic"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


With altered font size, arrow goes up
<div class="tablelike">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="tablelike">
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell"><div class="recipe recipe_small common_recipe common_bg">&nbsp;</div></div>
          <div class="table-cell"><div class="recipe recipe_small uncommon_recipe uncommon_bg">&nbsp;</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell"><div class="recipe recipe_small rare_recipe">&nbsp;</div></div>
          <div class="table-cell"><div class="recipe recipe_small epic_recipe epic_bg">&nbsp;</div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="recipe recipe_large rare_recipe rare_bg">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="recipe"><span title="Can be crafted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up glyphicon-large epic"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property should do what you need:

```css
.recipe {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.recipe_small {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}

.recipe_large {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.common_recipe {
  border-color: #5e5e5e;
}

.uncommon_recipe {
  border-color: green;
}

.rare_recipe {
  border-color: blue;
}

.epic_recipe {
  border-color: purple;
}

.common_bg {
  background-color: #5e5e5e;
}

.uncommon_bg {
  background-color: green;
}

.rare_bg {
  background-color: blue;
}

.epic_bg {
  background-color: purple;
}

.tablelike {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell,
.table-head {
  display: table-cell;
}

.table-head {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.glyphicon-large {
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.fantamondi.it/cotli/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> Normal size, everything is in line
<div class="tablelike">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="tablelike">
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="recipe recipe_small common_recipe common_bg">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="recipe recipe_small uncommon_recipe uncommon_bg">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="recipe recipe_small rare_recipe">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="recipe recipe_small epic_recipe epic_bg">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="recipe recipe_large rare_recipe rare_bg">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="recipe"><span title="Can be crafted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up epic"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


With altered font size, arrow goes up
<div class="tablelike">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="tablelike">
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="recipe recipe_small common_recipe common_bg">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="recipe recipe_small uncommon_recipe uncommon_bg">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="recipe recipe_small rare_recipe">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="recipe recipe_small epic_recipe epic_bg">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="recipe recipe_large rare_recipe rare_bg">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="recipe"><span title="Can be crafted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up glyphicon-large epic"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know why but here the code seems to work properly, when i put it back into the original page is broke again. Anyway i've solved putting the `vertical-align` property to the `table-cell`. Thanks